# Named variables from Python for use in Bash source without temp file

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to get multiple variables from Python to be usable as variables within Bash. Although I have python as the source, it could be any programme/script, but not a file.

I can get source to do the job with a temp file. So I guess the question is, how do I pipe from a script output to source?

The source python could output any and/or multiple key=value so simply x=$(python script) does not work.

Python snip example

```
print("STARTDATE=" + STARTDATE)
print("STARTTIME=" + STARTTIME)
```

Output

```
STARTDATE=06/15/2021
STARTTIME=15:46:21.00
```

Bash working example with temp file

```
python script > temp.file
source temp.file
echo $STARTDATE
```

Echo is just for debugging here, I would be doing work on the variables

Failed attempts:

`source python script`

`source <(python script)`

`eval $(python script)`

Comment: try `python script | source /dev/stdin`?

Comment: Try this command:
 **eval \`python script\`**

Comment: Hi @LeiYang I get an error, I don't think it sees it as a file "source: not found
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr"

Comment: Hi @VictorLee, that works now I've actually set the scrip to use Bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need spaces around the strings and will also need to ensure that there are no spaces before or after "=" and so:

```
print("STARTDATE=\"" + STARTDATE + "\"")
print("STARTTIME=\"" + STARTTIME + "\"")
```

Making sure that you are using a bash shell and not sh, you should then be able to action the script and set the variables with:

```
source <(./script.py)
```

Or in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source <(./script.py)
```

Comment: Hi @raman-sailopal, this fails with (note "yorp" is just my testing script): ./yorp: 16: ./yorp: Syntax error: "(" unexpected",

Comment: I've just realised I was being a noob! In one of the systems I use sh=bash, but on others it's not. Process Substitution required Bash. This at the top and it works #!/bin/bash. 
@RamanSailopal I've marked yours as the answer, but would you mind adding my Bash realisation to make it complete, thanks.